# React Native Facebook logInWithReadPermissions not working

Tags: facebook, react-native, authentication, expo, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to use the react-native-fbsdk to get a user's access token. Upon calling the logInWithReadPermissions method, I keep getting an error that says "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions')"

I installed the npm dependency and imported it:

```
import { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk'
```

The class method loginWithFacebook looks like this:

```
logInWithFacebook = () => {
  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions([ 'public_profile', 'user_friends' ]).then(
    (result) => {
      if(result.isCanceled) {
        alert('Login cancelled')
      } else {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(({ accessToken }) => {
          console.log('Access Token : ', accessToken)
        })
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error('error : ', error)
    }
  )
}
```

I've tried clearing my cache, moving the project to my Documents directory, re-installing all npm packages... and still, I keep getting this error. [Click here to see the Expo debugging screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4nRf.jpg)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use libraries that require native code configuration via react-native link with a standard Expo project. In order to use said libraries, you need to detach and use ExpoKit. Here are the docs regarding ExpoKit: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html

With that said, we do have a Facebook API that may do what you need that is built into the Expo SDK. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook.html

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, `logInWithReadPermissions` is a method from **old** react-native-fbsdk version 0.8.0.

Now you should use `logInWithPermissions` since you have react-native-fbsdk version 0.10.0.